# Resolving heteroscedasticity in Gamma GLMM glmmTMB

Tags: heteroscedasticity, glmm, gamma-distribution

I am investigating the effect of predictor variables population.size (continuous), farm.type (categorical) and control measure y.n (binary) on my response variable outbreak duration (continuous). I believed the best distribution to account for was a Gamma distribution and when running my model and testing the assumptions using the DHARMa package I have found that there is heteroscedasticity (one of my three horizontal lines is red and wavey. Additionally in some cases the KS test is violated.

I am not sure how I can resolve this issue or what my next steps should be. I have attempted to account for a variable "o.country" but this doesn't seem to make much difference to the assumptions.

Would you please be able to offer advice on what the issue here might be and how I can go about resolving this. It has been suggested that I should account for potential time-dependent patterns by making time a predictor variable. however, I am not sure how to go about doing this as my response variable is in fact a measure of time in days and is likely to have a time-dependent pattern.

please find a link to my data block below due to dataset being too large to print:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f77BfwbxDAyDQawAp6QAg45s72RflgdD8Y1jbOqBfK0/edit?usp=sharing